# Order of 3d objects plotted with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to visualize a boat going through waves. I plot a sea surface using plot_surface and the boat is a collection of 3d patches. No matter how I set the order of elements they always appear such that the 3d surface covers the boat. I want the boat to be more visible. Tried plot_wireframe instead of surface but the lines still go on top. Any ideas?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d as mp3d

L=180 # wavelength
Nx=256
dx=4.0*L/Nx
kxi=int(Nx*dx/L)
kx=2*np.pi*kxi/dx/Nx
L=2*np.pi/kx
omega=np.sqrt(9.81*2*np.pi/L)
ship_nodes=20*(np.array([[0,0,0],[-5,-2,-1],[-5,-2,1],[5,-2,1],[5,-2,-1],[-5,2,-1],[-5,2,1],[5,2,1],[5,2,-1],[7,0,-1],[7,0,1]],dtype=np.float32))+np.array([Nx*dx/2,Nx*dx/2,0])
x=ship_nodes
ship_planes=[x[1:5],x[5:9],x[[2,6,7,3]],x[[1,4,8,5]],x[[1,2,6,5]],x[[3,10,7]],x[[4,9,8]],x[7:11],x[[3,4,9,10]]]
X,Y=np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0,Nx*dx,Nx),np.linspace(0,Nx*dx,Nx))
A=np.zeros((Nx,Nx),dtype=np.complex64)
A[int(Nx/2)+kxi,int(Nx/2)]=10.0j
Z=np.real(np.fft.ifftn(np.fft.ifftshift(A), axes=(0, 1))*(Nx*Nx))
fig=plt.figure('Ship')
ax=mp3d.Axes3D(fig)
p=mp3d.art3d.Poly3DCollection(ship_planes,zorder=10)
p.set_facecolor((0,0.5,0))
p.set_edgecolor('k')
p.set_zorder(10)
p1=ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z.T,zorder=1,lw=1)
p1.set_zorder(1)
c1=ax.add_collection3d(p1)
c2=ax.add_collection3d(p)
ax.set_xlim3d(0,Nx*dx)
ax.set_ylim3d(0,Nx*dx)
ax.set_zlim3d(-Nx*dx/2,Nx*dx/2)
fig.show()
```

[Picture example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRY1d.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

`zorder` doesn't seem to work here. One way would be to make the wave surface a bit transparent using `alpha`. Also, you don't need to add `c1=ax.add_collection3d(p1)` to your code because `ax.plot_surface` already adds the surface to the plot

```
p=mp3d.art3d.Poly3DCollection(ship_planes)
p.set_facecolor((0,0.5,0))
p.set_edgecolor('k')
p1=ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z.T,lw=1, alpha=0.7)
c2=ax.add_collection3d(p)
```

[image]

Comment: Started to use alpha blending myself but the result does not look good. Strange that the surface plot is always on top even though both are the patch collections.

Comment: An alternative would be to add some offset to the z-coordinates of the ship so that it shows up above the surface

Comment: I have tried it as well. The surface still looks to be on top.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable zorder automatically and adjust it by yourself:

```
fig=plt.figure(computed_zorder=False)
```